# linux + tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, terminal

I use in my bash script the tput command in order to colored the text

as

```
tput setaf 2
```

when I run the script from putty or console every thing is ok

but when I run some external WIN application engine that run the script via SSH
the we get the following error on tput

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

please advice what need to set ( ENV or else ) in my bash script in order to use the tput command ?

what value need to set for $TERM ( in my bash script ) ?

Answer (score 0):

call your shell with the following syntax:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "TERM=xterm script.sh"
```

or

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "export TERM=xterm ; script.sh"
```

Replace the following:

*user* by your user name

*127.0.0.1* by your remote IP

*script.sh* by your script name

Answer (score 0):

MY WORKING SOLUTION FOR THE TPUT-PROBLEM:

```
# when $TERM is empty (non-interactive shell), then expand tput with '-T xterm-256color'
[[ ${TERM}=="" ]] && TPUTTERM='-T xterm-256color' \
                  || TPUTTERM=''

declare -r    RES='tput${TPUTTERM} sgr0'       REV='tput${TPUTTERM} rev'
declare -r    fRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 1'    bRD='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 1'
declare -r    fGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setaf 2'    bGN='tput${TPUTTERM} setab 2'
...
echo ${fRD}" RED Message: ${REV} This message is RED REVERSE. "${RES}
echo ${fGN}" GREEN Message: ${REV} This message is GREEN REVERSE. "${RES}
...
```

---

This way it makes no sense if there's an interactive or a non-interactive shell - tput still works fine.